# How to rotate list of figures in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, rotating

As above, how can I rotate list of figures in LaTeX? I've tried to use rotating package, but it doesn't work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document} 
   \begin{rotate}{-90}
       \listoffigures
   \end{rotate}
\end{document}
```

If I try to print a list of figures in a traditional way, it shows ok, but if I try to rotate it, I get an error:

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item`. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... `\listoffigures`.

Also, If I try to display normal text, not a list of figures, it shows ok.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would need to put the \listoffigures in a \parbox, then rotate that, but it's a very odd thing to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It's mentioned in my project from school. I also don't see any point in doing that, but :)

Comment: Insert it in landscape mode: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document} 
   \begin{landscape}
       \listoffigures
   \end{landscape}
\end{document}`

Comment: does it really ask you to rotate the **list** of figures?